# How the code is working here in the subclass?

Tags: java

```
package practice;

class person{  
    private String firstname;  
    private String lastname;

    public person(String firstname,String lastname){
        set_first(firstname);
        set_last(lastname);
    }

    public String get_first() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void set_first(String firstname) {
        this.firstname=firstname;
    }
    public void set_last(String lastname) {
        this.lastname=lastname;
    }
    public String get_last() {
        return lastname;
    }
}

class employee extends person {  
    private int empid;  
    public employee(String firstname, String lastname, int empid) {  
        super(firstname,lastname);  
        set_empid(empid);  
    }

    public void set_empid(int empid) {
        this.empid=empid;
    }
    public int get_empid() {
        return empid;
    }
}

class testing_super_keyword {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
        employee emp=new employee("Paul","Anderson",1234);  
        System.out.println(emp.get_first()+"  "+emp.get_last());  
        System.out.println(emp.get_empid());  
    }
}
```

I got two classes here person superclass and employee subclass. So i just wanted to know this code isn't supposed to work as the firstname and lastname variable is private in superclass? But how the subclass i.e employee is inheriting those members and using it??

I thought private variable of superclass cant be inherited so how come it works fine here?

I am totally confused please help......

Comment: `private` fields `firstname` and `lastname` are not being inherited. Public functions `get_first()` and `get_last()` are the ones that are being inherited. If you try calling `firstname` and `lastname` instead of functions you would get an error.

Comment: because you used encapsulation in your superclass. it means that your fields are private, but they have public getter/setter methods, which allows to the child classes to access/modify private fields.

Comment: Where in your `employee` class do you believe the private fields of  `person` are being accessed?

Comment: I meant that in the subclass object we don't hv access to the private members but these members are there in the subclass object which the subclass is not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> private variable of superclass cant be inherited

Yes, you are absolutely right, they won't be inheriting. But in your code, you are not accessing those fields directly right?

```
public employee(String firstname,String lastname,int empid){  
    super(firstname,lastname);  
    set_empid(empid);  
}
```

Here you are passing parameters (from the main method) to your `employee` constructor, the names of parameters are similar to the fields in `person`, but they are not the same. You can change parameters names like this and it will still work fine.

```
public employee(String fName, String lName,int empid){  
    super(fName,lName);  
    set_empid(empid);  
}
```

Here the parameter values are taken into `super` class constructor and its private fields are initialized and then `empid` of `employee` is initialized.

```
System.out.println(emp.get_first()+"  "+emp.get_last());  
System.out.println(emp.get_empid());
```

Here also you are not accessing the `private` fields directly, you are calling the public methods which will be inherited to the `employee` and can be called on its reference.

Keeping members of a class as private and their behaviours (methods) as public is a part of `encapsulation`, so that you cannot directly access then but can set and get its value using public methods.

PS : Try to make the getters and setters using the IDE, if it gives the option and try to follow naming conventions for classes and methods.

Comment: So can I assume that private members of the superclass is present in the subclass objects and they need to initialize only by a getter and setter method and not directly in the sub claases?

Comment: You can't access private members of a class in its subclass. I didn't get what you actually meant by the presence, you can use the getters and setters to access as well as set the private members value.

Comment: I meant that in the subclass object we don't hv access to the private members but these members are there in the subclass object which the subclass is not aware of?

Comment: Private members of the superclass won't be available in the subclass, you can only access them using getters/setters. So in the subclass object, you cannot access the private members directly. Members of a class will come to its subclass only after inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Although, the private variables of parent class are not inherited by child class i.e employee but there are public functions that are called `getter` and `setter` that allows to access the private members of class from its sub-class.

```
public String get_first() {
  return firstname;
}
public void set_first(String firstname) {
  this.firstname=firstname;
}
public void set_last(String lastname) {
  this.lastname=lastname;
}
public String get_last() {
  return lastname;
}
```

You see when you want to access firstname from parent, you'll call `get_first()` from employee object to get the firstname. If you want to set the firstname you'll call `set_first("name")` to set the name. Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

lets review how **firstname** and **lastname** are being initialized here:

1. in subclass constructor firstname, lastname has been taken
2. then in the body of constructor by `super(firstname,lastname)`, **firstname** and **lastname** pass to the parent (i.e. Person) to be taken care of.
3. so assume we are now in the parent constructor (Person) so, By calling  `set_first(firstname)` and `set_last(lastname)` , parameters firstname and lastname is being set in parent class itself with the values which passed from the child constructor (i.e. Employee)

> Regarding this description there is no violation.

The violation happens if you want to initialize private variable directly in Employee class as :

```
public employee(String firstname,String lastname,int empid){  
    this.firstname=firstname;      //Violation 
    this.lastname=lastname;        //Violation 
    set_empid(empid);  
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that every time to initialize the private variable in  the subclass we need to use a getter and setter method like this ? or else its not possible to initialize them?